# Why do I get: 'rspec' is not recognized as an internal or external command?

Tags: ruby

I have a file that's coded incorrectly on purpose so that when `rspec` is run, it would show the errors in the source code. However, when I run it, it shows me this error instead: `'rspec' is not recognized as an internal or external command`. This is definitely not a source code error. What should I do?

If it helps, I've downloaded Ruby bundle @ http://railsinstaller.org/en .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you install rspec?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko I'm very new to Ruby. How can I check it it's installed? I did run `gem install rspec` and `gem install rspec-its` .

Comment: if you have run `gem install rspec` and it succeeded - it is installed :)

Comment: I see. Thanks. I think the answer to your prior question would be yes now.

Comment: Oh wait, I think I did it at the wrong directory. I've tried running `gem install rspec` again, this time @ "C:\RailsInstaller". Now it shows this error: `ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'rspec' (>=0), here is why: Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)`

Comment: here you go :) Now google how to solve this ssl_connect problem (you'd basically need to specify `http://rubygems.org` instead of `https://rubygems.org` as a source), then install the gem and it will work

Comment: @JohnEscobia http://guides.rubygems.org/ssl-certificate-update/

Comment: @AndreyDeineko solving SSL problems by not using SSL? ;-)

Comment: @Stefan this is a bullet-proof solution. E.g. solving encoding issues by forcing ASCII7 and stripping out all the garbage always worked for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is more than one way of solving this. However, I find that @Stefan's answer via comment is the easiest way to go around it.

Simply go to `http://guides.rubygems.org/ssl-certificate-update/`, everything is explained there.

Cheers! :)